# Python object returning function only with getattr

Tags: python, metaprogramming, attr, getattr

On http://effbot.org/zone/python-getattr.htm it states that

> ```
> Python’s getattr function is used to fetch an attribute from an object, using 
> a string object instead of an identifier to identify the
> attribute. In other words, the following two statements are
> equivalent:
>
>     value = obj.attribute
>     value = getattr(obj, "attribute")
> ```

What is confuses me is that I have a module with a class with dynamic classmethod generation. I know that the generation works because calling __dict__ returns

```
 >>> errors.__dict__
mappingproxy({'__module__': 'utils.errors', '__weakref__': 
<attribute '__weakref__' of 'errors' objects>,'404': <classmethod object at 
0x7fe547c23190>, '500': <classmethod object at 0x7fe547c23210>, '403': 
<classmethod object at 0x7fe547c23110>, '400': <classmethod object at 
0x7fe547c23090>})
```

What is confusing me is the face that getattr works, while calling the attribute directly does not

```
>>> errors.404("asdf")
  File "<console>", line 1
    errors.404("asdf")
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> getattr(errors,'404')("asdf")
{'error': 'Page Not Found', 'code': 404, 'message': 'asdf'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identifiers starting with a number are not valid identifiers ([ref](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers)).

Comment: It seems odd that they would allow setattr for invalid identifiers.

Comment: I would rather say it's odd they would allow dot-style attribute lookup whilst limiting the allowed names of attributes to be looked up. It's just a syntax sugar for `__getattribute__`.